# Blackberry Browserfield not opening any webpage

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am a newbie just trying to open simple website in browserfield of Blackberry simulator 9860 os 7.1 . My MDS is running still it is giving request failed...~120000 error. I have followed instructions from many sites but unable to open webpage in blackberry browser. Also the url is working in simulators browser but not in my own browser. Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use a BrowserFieldErrorHandler in your BrowserFieldfor try to catch the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it in simulator , i will suggest you to check in real device.

Look at browserfield Demo in samples provided by Blackberry in Eclipse plugin.

```
<Directory>:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack<JDE version>\components\samples\com\rim\samples\device\browser
```

Comment: i dont have a device yet..i have checked browserfield demo also but it is also not ruuning.

Comment: i have checked it on my device it was working but on simulator , browser field was not preparing.Check it on Blackberry 9800 Simulator , i was able to view browser field on this simulator.

Comment: i am using os 7.1..will it run on blackberry 9800 simulator??

Comment: if you have set JRE ver as 6.0 or above it will work, if it is set on 7.1 it will not. in second case , degrade the JRE version & test it.